# Not displaying decimals if double is a whole number?

Tags: java, double, decimal, calculator

I am making a graphical calculator program in Java and have a method that performs an operation based on user input, and returns a double to be displayed in a `JTextField`. However, I would like the result to be displayed as a whole number, without a following `".0"` where there are no significant digits after the decimal point, but still display decimal points when necessary. What's the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Perhaps convert to a string and manipulate it there by making a conditional if the trailing two characters are `.0`?

Comment: How would I write a conditional to check the trailing characters?

Comment: There is a better response to the question which uses [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html). Please see Reimeus' answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `DecimalFormat` for suppressing the trailing characters, e.g.:

```
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
double doubleFromTextField = Double.parseDouble(myField.getText());
System.out.println(format.format(doubleFromTextField));
```

Comment: That helps with formatting the output in all cases, but I only want to eliminate the trailing decimals if the trailing decimal is ".0". How would I write a conditional to only format the output if the double is a whole number? Thanks for your help.

Comment: This example does in effect do what you as asking, any significant (non-zero) digits after the decimal point will be displayed, so no need for additional checks.

Comment: I'm so dumb, I didn't notice it was printing the correct answer I wanted into the console instead of the JTextField. Thank you Reimeus!

Comment: The important thing to remember is that the # means "No leading zeroes" which includes trailing zeros after decimal point. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html